# Hadoop Mapreduce Input Splits. Will this hurt my algorithm?

Tags: java, mapreduce

I am currently writing a MapReduce program in Java, querying the Amazon metadata found here: http://snap.stanford.edu/data/amazon-meta.html

When processing the input with my map function, I read each line, storing info about each product. After hearing about how input splits work, is there a chance that the file could be split in the middle of one of the product "paragraphs", ruining my algorithm for attempting to analyze that product?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't, however I can see where you're coming from. Try "scanner" or other techniques. I found a question similar to yours: [Hadoop Mapreduce Input Splits. Will this hurt my algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49471505/hadoop-mapreduce-input-splits-will-this-hurt-my-algorithm)

Comment: That link goes to this same question. Was that intentional?